# C# and Angular - Cross Origin Error

Tags: c#, angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

We are developing web site in Angular 5. Back end has been developed using .Net Web API and SQL Server. The website would be deployed on Azure and would be accessible both from internet as well as intranet.

We have configured CROSS Origin settings and it is working fine. Now we have integrated Ping federation SSO using SAML. Now site is getting redirected to 3rd party login page and giving error **"No access control allow region header is present on the resource. Origin null is therefore not allowed access". Null is not allowed”** before redirecting to login page. Tried by specifying multiple origins separated by comma but still getting the same error. Below is sample code.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
cors.Origins.Add("https://3rd party url");  
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The same is working fine if SSO is accessed from web api directly by typing url. Please provide any pointers to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy in your client and change client's origin to whatever you want.

**The advantages of this solution are :**

1. You don't need to define CORS in you'r back-end ( increase security )
2. You don't need to be worry about your client as well as you just run your project via **npm start**, as soon as you want to release your application you can run **ng build** command and proxy will be ignored from your setting.

For using proxy

1. edit `"start"` of your `package.json` to look below

   `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`
2. create a new file called `proxy.conf.json` in the root of the project and inside of that define your proxies like below

   ```
   {
     "/api/*": {
       "target": "http://localhost:56492",
       "secure": "false"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Important thing is that you use `npm start` instead of `ng serve`

Now in you'r service.ts , post/get requests url instead of localhost:56492/... just type /api/Film.

Read more from here : [Proxy Setup angular 2 cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: This approach is not working and I am still getting same error.